# How to divide rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I am trying to use pandas to divide the rows by 3, but I was met with an error

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Any suggestions or alternatives to do this would be appreciated!

Code used:

```
x = [data]
for dataset in x :
    dataset.loc[dataset['zipcode'] == 98008] = dataset['price'].mul(1/3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different numbers of rows and columns in your example. On the left, you use select rows but all columns. On the right, you use all rows, but only one column. This should work:

```
dataset.loc[dataset['zipcode'] == 98008, 'price'] /= 3
```